# How can I pass values between too many classes?

Tags: java, class

I have three classes(containing Main class) with getters,setters and constructors.In one class called Airplane I set two private integers rows and columns and I ask for an input from the user at Main class. After that I want to set the size of an array in a class called Flight by this integers rows and columns.How should I do that?

I tried to create a scanner object and an object from Airplane at Flight class but I realised that I ask for another different value that I have already set in Main. Is there any way to get the value rows and columns from the main to put in in Flight class?

Airplane class:

```
public class Airplane {
   private String code;
   private String description;
   private int rows;
   private int columns;
```

Flight class:

```
public class Flight {

private String ticketCode;
private String AirportDeparture;
private String AirportLanding;
private int Seats[][];
private String menuCode;
private int NumOfSeats;
private int NumOfTakenSeats;
private LocalDate dateOfDeparture;
private LocalTime timeOfDeparture;
```

Main class:

```
 Airplane airp = new Airplane();
 System.out.println("Give a code.");
 String code = scanner.nextLine();
 airp.setCode(code);
 System.out.println("Give number of rows.");
 int rows = scanner.nextInt();
 airp.setRows(rows);
 System.out.println("Give number of columns.");
 int columns = scanner.nextInt();
 airp.setColumns(columns);
 System.out.println("Give number of business class rows.");
 int BCrows = scanner.nextInt();
 airp.setBCrows(BCrows);
```

Comment: shouldn't your Flight class extend Airplane class. That should solve this issue?

Comment: A flight is not really a plane but the `flight` should have a reference to the place (association). So you have the row and column of the place.

Comment: Unrelated: please read about java naming conventions. Field/variable names go camelCase in Java. Always. It is really not helpful for your readers that sometimes you do that, but then you go UpperCase.

Comment: @CyrilCherian My code is based at a certain description and it doesn't say something about extend like it asks for other classes.

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you for your instruction! I'll fix it as soon as possible!

Comment: well, in that case maybe you need composition. Flight has an Airplane.
And when you set the row and column it passes it into the composed Airplane?

Comment: @CyrilCherian Honestly: not at all. A flight is *concept*, an idea, something that denotes an "event" to take place. A plane is none of that. And it is rarely a good idea to use inheritance solely to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A flight is associate with a plane so it should simply have a reference to it.

```
public class Flight {

    private Airplane airplane;
    private int[][] seats;

}
```

And when you set the plane, you will be able to initialize the array with the value of the plane.

```
public void setPlane(Airplane airplane){
    this.airplane = airplane;
    this.seats = new int[airplane.getRows()][airplane.getColumns()];
}
```

*Note that I used a setter, this could/should be in constructor.*

Now, we can argue if the plane should have a reference to its flights, but that's not really the point here.

Comment: That's probably correct @GhostCat , I don't have any knowledge on that. I could reply that `Airplane` just define the model, not the specific place ;) thanks for your input, this would definitely be the best way to go to be able to allocate plane when needed and ensure that two planes are not used for different flight (BTW, I always like "nitty picky" comment !!)

Comment: You are welcome @MikePanrs. I didn't try to solve this problem with the best approach. I mostly post this answer because it was complicated to explain in a comment. If you have some question about this (not to far from the original problem), don't hesitate.